# How to speed up of File transfer with Web-Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, data-transfer

I've tried to transfer a video file to public server named 'INFURA'

But it was too slow than I expected. (about <1mb/s)

**I think if I split a file to transfer, I would get a better speed.** I wrote some js code for this and it worked.

**but then, each chunk had 1/n speed.** I thought It was because even though I split a file and called a function many times, single thread processed this so transfer speed didn't up

so I re-wrote my code to use several web-worker to do this in background.

**Transferring? It was okay. but it didn't work with the speed. it was same with just splitting the file like above.**

Did I think wrong the reason why it was slow? **Isn't a thread created every time I create a web worker?**

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

  <!-- loading the minified version -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs-http-client/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs-api@9.0.0/dist/index.js" integrity="sha384-5bXRcW9kyxxnSMbOoHzraqa7Z0PQWIao+cgeg327zit1hz5LZCEbIMx/LWKPReuB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/9.0.0/bignumber.js" integrity="sha256-TYZ2kR74G+TqMIiLuKpB57VUTNKhGFknyOKgRYqxhnw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">IPFS Client TEST (Infura)</h1>

  <select id="ipfs_client">
    <option value="infura" selected="selected">infura</option>
    <option value="private_gateway">private gateway</option>
  </select>

  <select id="num_of_chunks">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>

  </select>

  <div id="" style="margin-top:40px">
    <h2>file upload</h2>
    <input type="file" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" />
    <input type="button" value="upload" id="send_ipfs" onclick="javascript:sendIpfs();" />
    <input type="button" value="upload_webworker" id="send_ipfs_webworker" onclick="javascript:sendIpfsWebWorker();" />
    <a id="file_url"></a>

  </div>

  <div id="" style="margin-top:40px">
    <h2> file download </h2>
    <input type="text" id="downloadHash" placeholder="download hash" onchange="" />
    <input type="button" value="get" id="get_ipfs" onclick="javascript:getIpfs();" />
    <a id="linkToDownload" href="" download=""></a>

  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:80px">
    <h1>IPFS Node TEST (js-ipfs Node)</h1>
    <div id="" style="margin-top:40px">
      <h2>upload(browser Node) </h2>
      <input type="file" id="fileBrowserNode" onchange="loadFileForBrowserNode(event)" />
      <input type="button" value="upload" id="send_ipfs_to_browser_node" onclick="javascript:sendIpfsToBrowserNode()" />
      <a id="file_url"></a>

    </div>

    <div id="" style="margin-top:40px">
      <h2> download(browser Node) </h2>
      <input type="text" id="downloadHashBrowserNode" placeholder="download hash" onchange="" />
      <input type="button" value="get" id="get_ipfs_from_browser_node" onclick="javascript:getIpfsFromBrowserNode()" />
      <a id="linkToDownloadBrowserNode" href="" download=""></a>

    </div>

    <div id="" style="margin-top:40px">
      <h2> stat bandwidth </h2>
      TotalIn:<span id="bwTotalIn"></span><br>
      TotalOut:<span id="bwTotalOut"></span><br>
      RateIn:<span id="bwRateIn"></span><br>
      RateOut:<span id="bwRateOut"></span><br>
    </div>

    <div id="web_worker_test" style="margin-top:40px">
      <h2> Webworker Test </h2>
      ouput: <span id="web_worker_output"></span>
      <button id="worker_run" value="run">run</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


<script>
  var downloadedfiles
  var onloadfile
  var numOfChunks = 0;
  var uploadBuf = new Array(numOfChunks);
  var downloadBuf = new Array(numOfChunks);
  var fullLength
  var ipfs = new Array(numOfChunks)
  var uploadedChunkCnt = 0
  var hashBuffer = new Array(numOfChunks)
  var worker = new Array();
  var uploadStartTime
  $(document).ready(function() {
    numOfChunks = $('#num_of_chunks').val()

    chooseClient = function() {
      var selectedClient = $('#ipfs_client').val();
      console.log(selectedClient);
      if (selectedClient == 'infura') {
        for (var i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
          ipfs[i] = window.IpfsHttpClient({
            host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
            port: 5001,
            protocol: 'https'
          });
        }
        $('#title').html('IPFS Client TEST (Infura)');
      } else if (selectedClient == 'private_gateway') {
        ipfs = window.IpfsHttpClient({
          host: 'devipfs.nemodax.com',
          port: 5001,
          protocol: 'https'
        })
        $('#title').html('IPFS Client TEST (devipfs Private Gateway)');
      }
    }


    function init() {
      numOfChunks = $('#num_of_chunks').val()

      worker = new Array()

      if (typeof(onloadfile) != 'undefined') {
        fullLength = onloadfile.result.byteLength;
        chunkLength = fullLength / numOfChunks
        for (var i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
          var chunk
          if (i == numOfChunks - 1) { // last chunk process
            chunk = onloadfile.result.slice(i * chunkLength, fullLength)
          } else {
            chunk = onloadfile.result.slice(i * chunkLength, (i + 1) * chunkLength)
          }
          uploadBuf[i] = Ipfs.Buffer(chunk)
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {

        worker.push(new Worker("./IPFSUpload_worker.js"))

        worker[i].onmessage = function(event) {
          uploadedChunkCnt += event.data.uploadedChunkCnt
          console.log("The number of Worker Thread which has done: ", uploadedChunkCnt);
          hashBuffer[event.data.thread_no] = event.data.hashBuffer
          if (uploadedChunkCnt == numOfChunks) {
            console.log("All chunks are downloaded. Creating indexHash on IPFS...")
            var chunkMap = ""
            for (var j = 0; j < numOfChunks; j++) {
              chunkMap = chunkMap + hashBuffer[j] + ','
            }
            ipfs[0].add(Ipfs.Buffer.from(chunkMap)).then((res) => {
              indexHash = res[0].hash
              var uploadFileSize = fullLength // byte
              var uploadEndTime = new Date();
              var uploadInterval = uploadEndTime - uploadStartTime // ms
              var uploadSpeed = uploadFileSize / uploadInterval // byte / ms == kb/s
              console.log('* upload hash:', indexHash)
              console.log('* chunkMap:', chunkMap);
              console.log('* upload path:', event.data.path)
              console.log('* upload size:', formatSizeUnits(uploadFileSize))
              console.log('* upload speed:', uploadSpeed, 'kb/s')
              console.log('* upload interval:', uploadInterval / 1000, 'sec')
            });
          }
        }
      }
      chooseClient()
    }


    $('#num_of_chunks').on('change', function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
        if (typeof(worker[i]) != 'undefined') {
          worker[i].terminate()
        }
      }
      init()
    })

    init();
  })

  function sendIpfsWebWorker() {
    uploadStartTime = new Date();
    var path = $("#file").val().split("\\")[2]
    console.log("> start upload (api): ", path, uploadStartTime)
    uploadedChunkCnt = 0;
    var params = new Array()
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
      data = {
        "thread_no": i,
        //"ipfs": ipfs, // 메소드는 직렬화 할수 없다..
        "functionToCall": "",
        "selectedClient": $('#ipfs_client').val(),
        "numOfChunksInThread": 1,
        "uploadBuf": uploadBuf[i],
        "downloadBuf": downloadBuf[i],
        "fullLength": fullLength,
        "path": path,
        "uploadedChunkCnt": uploadedChunkCnt
        //results:,
        //hashBuffer:,
      }

      params.push(data)

      params[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(params[i]));
      worker[i].postMessage(params[i])
      //console.log(params[i])
      //console.log("stringify params:", params[i])
    }
    //console.log("stringify params:", params[0])
  }


  async function getBandWidth() {
    bw = await node.stats.bw()

    $('#bwTotalIn').html(formatSizeUnits(bw.totalIn.toString().slice(0, 5)));
    $('#bwTotalOut').html(formatSizeUnits(bw.totalOut.toString().slice(0, 5)));
    $('#bwRateIn').html(formatSizeUnits(bw.rateIn.toString().slice(0, 5)) + '/s');
    $('#bwRateOut').html(formatSizeUnits(bw.rateOut.toString().slice(0, 5)) + '/s');
  }




  const reader = new FileReader();

  var loadFile = function(event) {
    console.log('upload::');

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      console.log('onload::');

      onloadfile = reader
      //buf = Ipfs.Buffer(reader.result); // Convert data into buffer

      // split the file it will be uploaded

      fullLength = reader.result.byteLength;
      chunkLength = fullLength / numOfChunks

      for (var i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
        var chunk
        if (i == numOfChunks - 1) { // last chunk process
          chunk = reader.result.slice(i * chunkLength, fullLength)
        } else {
          chunk = reader.result.slice(i * chunkLength, (i + 1) * chunkLength)
        }
        uploadBuf[i] = Ipfs.Buffer(chunk)
      }

    };

    const file = document.getElementById("file");
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.files[0]); // Read Provided File

  };





  async function sendIpfs() {

    var uploadStartTime = new Date();
    console.log("> start upload (api): ", uploadStartTime)

    var path = $("#file").val().split("\\")[2]

    results = new Array(numOfChunks)
    hashBuffer = new Array(numOfChunks)
    uploadedChunkCnt = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
      var chunkStartTime = new Date();
      console.log("start upload chunk[", i, "](api): ", chunkStartTime)

      ipfs[i].add([{
        path: path + '.nemo.' + i,
        content: uploadBuf[i],
      }], {
        recursive: true,
        wrapWithDirectory: true
        //progress: (length) => {
        //  console.log(length);
        //}
      }).then((res) => {
        var token = res[0].path.split('.')
        var chunkNum = token[token.length - 1]
        results[chunkNum] = res;

        console.log(results[chunkNum]);
        var chunkEndTime = new Date();
        var chunkInterval = chunkEndTime - chunkStartTime // ms
        var chunkSize = uploadBuf[chunkNum].length // byte
        var speed = chunkSize / chunkInterval // byte / ms == kb/s
        console.log('interval upload chunk[', chunkNum, '](api): ', chunkInterval / 1000, 'size:', chunkSize / 1000, 'kb', speed, 'kb/s')

        hashBuffer[chunkNum] = results[chunkNum][1].hash;
        console.log(hashBuffer[chunkNum]);
        uploadedChunkCnt++;
        if (uploadedChunkCnt == numOfChunks) {
          var chunkMap = ""
          for (var j = 0; j < numOfChunks; j++) {
            chunkMap = chunkMap + hashBuffer[j] + ','
          }
          ipfs[0].add(Ipfs.Buffer.from(chunkMap)).then((res) => {
            indexHash = res[0].hash
            var uploadFileSize = fullLength // byte

            var uploadEndTime = new Date();
            var uploadInterval = uploadEndTime - uploadStartTime // ms
            var uploadSpeed = uploadFileSize / uploadInterval // byte / ms == kb/s
            console.log('* upload hash:', indexHash)
            console.log('* chunkMap:', chunkMap);
            console.log('* upload path:', path)
            console.log('* upload size:', formatSizeUnits(uploadFileSize))
            console.log('* upload speed:', uploadSpeed, 'kb/s')
            console.log('* upload interval:', uploadInterval / 1000, 'sec')
          });
        }
      })
    }
  }




  function formatSizeUnits(bytes) {
    if (bytes >= 1073741824) {
      bytes = (bytes / 1073741824).toFixed(2) + " GB";
    } else if (bytes >= 1048576) {
      bytes = (bytes / 1048576).toFixed(2) + " MB";
    } else if (bytes >= 1024) {
      bytes = (bytes / 1024).toFixed(2) + " KB";
    } else if (bytes > 1) {
      bytes = bytes + " bytes";
    } else if (bytes == 1) {
      bytes = bytes + " byte";
    } else {
      bytes = "0 bytes";
    }
    return bytes;
  }
</script>


</html>
```

```
IPFSUpload_worker.js


var window = {}
importScripts('./js/ipfs_index.js');
importScripts('./js/ipfs-http-client_index.js');
self.IpfsHttpClient = window.IpfsHttpClient
self.Ipfs = window.Ipfs


 function createClient(context) {

  context.ipfs = new Array(context.numOfChunksInThread)

  if (context.selectedClient == 'infura') {
    for (var i = 0; i < context.numOfChunksInThread; i++) {
      context.ipfs[i] = self.IpfsHttpClient({
        host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
        port: 5001,
        protocol: 'https'
      });
    }
  }
}


async function sendIpfsWebWorker(context) {
  createClient(context)
  console.log("context in worker: ", context)

  context.results = new Array(context.numOfChunksInThread)
  context.hashBuffer = new Array(context.numOfChunksInThread)
  context.uploadedChunkCnt = 0;


  for (var i = 0; i < context.numOfChunksInThread; i++) {
    var chunkStartTime = new Date();
    console.log("start upload chunk[", context.thread_no, "](api): ", chunkStartTime)

    context.ipfs[i].add([{
      path: context.path + '.nemo.' + context.thread_no,
      content: Ipfs.Buffer(context.uploadBuf.data),
    }], {
      recursive: true,
      wrapWithDirectory: true
      //progress: (length) => {
      //  console.log(length);
      //}
    }).then((res) => {
      var token = res[0].path.split('.')
      var chunkNum = token[token.length - 1]
      context.results[chunkNum] = res;

      console.log(context.results[chunkNum]);
      var chunkEndTime = new Date();
      var chunkInterval = chunkEndTime - chunkStartTime // ms
      var chunkSize = context.uploadBuf.data.length // byte
      var speed = chunkSize / chunkInterval // byte / ms == kb/s
      console.log('interval upload chunk[', chunkNum, '](api): ', chunkInterval / 1000, 'size:', chunkSize / 1000, 'kb', speed, 'kb/s')

      context.hashBuffer = context.results[chunkNum][1].hash;
      console.log(context.hashBuffer);
      context.uploadedChunkCnt++;

      var resultForMainThread = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context));
      postMessage(resultForMainThread);
      self.close()

    })
  }
}


function formatSizeUnits(bytes) {
  if (bytes >= 1073741824) {
    bytes = (bytes / 1073741824).toFixed(2) + " GB";
  } else if (bytes >= 1048576) {
    bytes = (bytes / 1048576).toFixed(2) + " MB";
  } else if (bytes >= 1024) {
    bytes = (bytes / 1024).toFixed(2) + " KB";
  } else if (bytes > 1) {
    bytes = bytes + " bytes";
  } else if (bytes == 1) {
    bytes = bytes + " byte";
  } else {
    bytes = "0 bytes";
  }
  return bytes;
}


onmessage = function(event){

  sendIpfsWebWorker(event.data);

}
```

**Below is the result logs.**

the number of chunks : 1

```
index.html:275 upload::
index.html:279 onload::
index.html:197 > start upload (api):  harry_potter_hermione_growth_spurt_snl_720p.mp4 Fri Aug 16 2019 09:48:28 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)
IPFSUpload_worker.js:39 context in worker:  {thread_no: 0, functionToCall: "", selectedClient: "infura", numOfChunksInThread: 1, uploadBuf: {…}, …}
IPFSUpload_worker.js:52 start upload chunk[ 0 ](api):  Fri Aug 16 2019 09:48:45 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)
IPFSUpload_worker.js:68 (2) [{…}, {…}]
IPFSUpload_worker.js:73 interval upload chunk[ 0 ](api):  15.69 size: 51340.408 kb 3272.1738687061825 kb/s
IPFSUpload_worker.js:76 QmNqHoM9cyNeXH1QLUZt2sZtBY8DgoYB8aD7WFBHccK5VD
index.html:154 The number of Worker Thread which has done:  1
index.html:157 All chunks are downloaded. Creating indexHash on IPFS...
index.html:168 * upload hash: QmPYTrBBZVHPusoUP3oRsaD3T25ccY2LFbUYCgAUvkWuFP
index.html:169 * chunkMap: QmNqHoM9cyNeXH1QLUZt2sZtBY8DgoYB8aD7WFBHccK5VD,
index.html:170 * upload path: harry_potter_hermione_growth_spurt_snl_720p.mp4
index.html:171 * upload size: 48.96 MB
index.html:172 * upload speed: 904.9797817771589 kb/s
index.html:173 * upload interval: 56.731 sec
```

[image: 1 chunk case]

the number of chunks : 5

```
index.html:275 upload::
index.html:279 onload::
index.html:197 > start upload (api):  harry_potter_hermione_growth_spurt_snl_720p.mp4 Fri Aug 16 2019 09:55:30 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)
IPFSUpload_worker.js:39 context in worker:  {thread_no: 0, functionToCall: "", selectedClient: "infura", numOfChunksInThread: 1, uploadBuf: {…}, …}
IPFSUpload_worker.js:52 start upload chunk[ 0 ](api):  Fri Aug 16 2019 09:55:33 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)
IPFSUpload_worker.js:39 context in worker:  {thread_no: 1, functionToCall: "", selectedClient: "infura", numOfChunksInThread: 1, uploadBuf: {…}, …}
IPFSUpload_worker.js:52 start upload chunk[ 1 ](api):  Fri Aug 16 2019 09:55:35 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)
IPFSUpload_worker.js:39 context in worker:  {thread_no: 2, functionToCall: "", selectedClient: "infura", numOfChunksInThread: 1, uploadBuf: {…}, …}
IPFSUpload_worker.js:52 start upload chunk[ 2 ](api):  Fri Aug 16 2019 09:55:37 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)
IPFSUpload_worker.js:39 context in worker:  {thread_no: 3, functionToCall: "", selectedClient: "infura", numOfChunksInThread: 1, uploadBuf: {…}, …}
IPFSUpload_worker.js:52 start upload chunk[ 3 ](api):  Fri Aug 16 2019 09:55:39 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)
IPFSUpload_worker.js:39 context in worker:  {thread_no: 4, functionToCall: "", selectedClient: "infura", numOfChunksInThread: 1, uploadBuf: {…}, …}
IPFSUpload_worker.js:52 start upload chunk[ 4 ](api):  Fri Aug 16 2019 09:55:42 GMT+0900 (한국 표준시)
IPFSUpload_worker.js:68 (2) [{…}, {…}]
IPFSUpload_worker.js:73 interval upload chunk[ 2 ](api):  16.813 size: 10268.081 kb 610.7227145661095 kb/s
IPFSUpload_worker.js:76 QmNzJqR3snVWQexVQA7crYNV4bJEjxMT9EHzhL5bSrBB5W
index.html:154 The number of Worker Thread which has done:  1
IPFSUpload_worker.js:68 (2) [{…}, {…}]
IPFSUpload_worker.js:73 interval upload chunk[ 0 ](api):  23.512 size: 10268.081 kb 436.71661279346716 kb/s
IPFSUpload_worker.js:76 QmSoruLfXkR51MVRUrcbBetGW4StkjfvxPAdn7yDoHdBUV
IPFSUpload_worker.js:68 (2) [{…}, {…}]
IPFSUpload_worker.js:73 interval upload chunk[ 3 ](api):  18.422 size: 10268.082 kb 557.3815003799805 kb/s
IPFSUpload_worker.js:76 QmY9KdJwnLsWcjYQCxNUECTFx82EhJf9CYBEZhQxqa38Ev
index.html:154 The number of Worker Thread which has done:  2
index.html:154 The number of Worker Thread which has done:  3
IPFSUpload_worker.js:68 (2) [{…}, {…}]
IPFSUpload_worker.js:73 interval upload chunk[ 1 ](api):  25.713 size: 10268.082 kb 399.3342667133357 kb/s
IPFSUpload_worker.js:76 Qmbx4svY1z6LhTje2gJinwQqNaDwjgt8fJsiNJh9fmSjnT
index.html:154 The number of Worker Thread which has done:  4
IPFSUpload_worker.js:68 (2) [{…}, {…}]
IPFSUpload_worker.js:73 interval upload chunk[ 4 ](api):  23.085 size: 10268.082 kb 444.79454191033136 kb/s
IPFSUpload_worker.js:76 QmeVYG86BNcqfhy6RjtGEM6dSFo33cfNFM4Ebniop4cAmf
index.html:154 The number of Worker Thread which has done:  5
index.html:157 All chunks are downloaded. Creating indexHash on IPFS...
index.html:168 * upload hash: QmdnbFQQJ4HhbvE2nNcJ9jhJmajGd83qdNxFkcQkgAXeNk
index.html:169 * chunkMap: QmSoruLfXkR51MVRUrcbBetGW4StkjfvxPAdn7yDoHdBUV,Qmbx4svY1z6LhTje2gJinwQqNaDwjgt8fJsiNJh9fmSjnT,QmNzJqR3snVWQexVQA7crYNV4bJEjxMT9EHzhL5bSrBB5W,QmY9KdJwnLsWcjYQCxNUECTFx82EhJf9CYBEZhQxqa38Ev,QmeVYG86BNcqfhy6RjtGEM6dSFo33cfNFM4Ebniop4cAmf,
index.html:170 * upload path: harry_potter_hermione_growth_spurt_snl_720p.mp4
index.html:171 * upload size: 48.96 MB
index.html:172 * upload speed: 1189.9503534592652 kb/s
index.html:173 * upload interval: 43.145 sec
```

[image: 5 chunks case]

> Adding 1 more questions after @kaiido's comments

I've one more question

I wrote the code like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {
          ipfs[i] = window.IpfsHttpClient({
            host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
            port: 5001,
            protocol: 'https',
          });
        }
...

for (var i = 0; i < numOfChunks; i++) {

ipfs[i].add([{
        path: path + '.nemo.' + i,
        content: uploadBuf[i],
      }], {
        recursive: true,
        wrapWithDirectory: true
      }).then((res) => {
        ... // do the job I intended.
      })
}
```

I thought that each ipfs instances are seperated with each connections so if there's enough physical bandwidth, each instances wouldn't affect each other.

My local machine's bandwidth is more than 10Mb/s at least(I tested in other ways). I think it will be sufficient compared to the slower baud rate I wrote with my code.

Nevertheless, the more chunks I split, the slower the speed of each chunks.(like 1/n) This is the part I don't accept

Comment: Are you assuming that the problem lies in your CPU not able to compute the data to be sent? Your CPU has almost nothing to do here. The culprit is in the network. Either your server or your ISP's bandwidth will be the limit setters. I sincerely doubt that parallel requests will make anything faster. And note that the request is not made on the same thread than your js, you'll win nothing by doing it from a Worker if you don't do any processing on the data before hand.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you very much for your reply. Because of my poor english, I'm not sure you mean low speed is not about web worker, just about bandwidth. then Isn't there anyway to fix that I can try?

Comment: That's indeed what I am saying, and while I must admit I don't know whether there could be solutions to speed things up, I doubt chunking your request is one of these, and I'm pretty sure Workers aren't.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you, Thank you so much. It was really helpful for me

Comment: I didn't get the read the complete code yet, but a few important points you need to know. One: there is a limit to the number of active connections in browser, creating more upload streams than this limit is pointless. For that matter, creating more than one is pointless. Two: uploading raw binary data uses little CPU, there's little to no benefit to using a worker. Three: There is no 100% guarantee that each worker will be a real system thread, only that they will be sandboxed from each other. Also, even if they were  real OS threads, it makes no sense to make more than 1 per CPU core.